# How do I update Drupal Distribution (Commerce Kickstart) on shared hosting environments?

Tags: commerce, updating, distributions

We currently run a Drupal Commerce site from GoDaddy C-Panel shared hosting environment.

I created the site with Commerce Kickstart and am now several distribution updates behind.

1. If that's the case, do I need to do the updates sequentially? (e.g. run three updates to get to the current version.)
2. Has anyone been successful with using Drush on GoDaddy to make these updates?

I read through the How-To documentation from Commerce Guys and wanted to run the updates with Drush based on the video posted there.

I followed the instructions on GoDaddy here: [How to install Drush on cPanel Shared Hosting](https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-drush-on-cpanel-shared-hosting-12396) Everything seemed to go well, but nothing happens when I try to run the drush commands. Any recommendations on how to troubleshoot this?

So I think I will need to do the security updates all manually for now.

Comment: Did you `cd` into the folder where your drupal is located? ex: `cd /var/www/drupal` and then once you're in here, do your drush command.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use drush and try with this article: https://duntuk.com/how-install-drush-godaddy-cpanel-hosting
   or
2. Update manually.

I would avoid the "update" interface in drupal. Reminder: All of the 100 or so modules are stored in the profile folder.